# Copy from a Workbook and paste it to any worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a vba to copy rows 24 to 28 of a existing template excel "Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx" and paste it to any current worksheet i am working one.

Below is the code, it currently only able to paste on excel file named "01 Add Products1.xlsx" , how do i change it to allow the below code to paste it on ANY current worksheet i am working on? Thanks!!

```vb
Sub FinalPricingDirectEnrollment()
'
' FinalPricingDirectEnrollment Macro
' FinalPricingDirectEnrollment
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'
    Windows("Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2:M2").Select
    Windows("01 Add Products1.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A2:M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "Microsoft Volume Licensing - Customer Price Sheet - Final Pricing"
    Range("D4:E4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "10/31/2020"
    Range("H7:I7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BDSG DH"
    Range("H8:I8").Select
    Workbooks("Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx").Rows("24:28").Copy _
    ActiveSheet.Range("A24")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is name (tab name) of the worksheet in workbook `Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx` whose rows you want to copy and is it the only worksheet? Do you only need values, or formulas and formats, too?

Comment: Hello the tab name of the  worksheet in workbook Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx is Cover Page

Comment: I am copying a set of merged rows with colours and bolding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy a Range

[Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)

You could do this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub finalpricingNOtenantsDirectEnrollment()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("Sample CPS - Direct.xlsx").Worksheets("Cover Page")
    ws.Rows("24:28").Copy ActiveSheet.Rows(24)
    ' or:
    'ws.Rows("24:28").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A24")
    ' Which is short for :
    'ws.Rows("24:28").Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A24")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works immediately, You are a life saver for a noob like me.. thanks!!